# Powershell script won't notify me when new file is created by a program

Tags: powershell

EDIT: partially solved. Works when I turn off xlsx. filter - even though the new file is an xlsx and should register

I am trying to get powershell to do an action when a program creates a new excel-file in a folder.

The script works for doing an action when I create a new file, or when some other user with access to the folder creates a new file, but not when the file is created by a program (SAS Customer Intelligence Studio). The file from the program is is the correct filetype (.xlsx), but no action takes place when it is created.

Here is the script:

```
$folder = '\\myexportfolder'
$filter = '*.xlsx'         

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $false             
NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
Invoke-Expression C:\PSscript\Action.ps1
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the filter? Does it pick up the programs file dumps?

Comment: Tried changing the filter to '*.*', which launched the action! However, the file is positively an xlsx file, so there is no reason why it shouldn't work with the filter on

Comment: Perhaps the file is not created as an xlsx at first? Just trying to help debug

Comment: You are probably right Matt. In any case I can live with the action running on all new files and just making a condition for file type

Comment: With your filter set to `'.'` if you add `Write-Host $args[1].FullName` to your `Register-ObjectEvent` script block you can see the full path and extension of the file triggering the event.  See [`FileSystemEventHandler` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filesystemeventhandler.aspx) and [`FileSystemEventArgs` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs.aspx).

Comment: Long shot but as far as I know SAS requires a lock on the xlsx file it is writing (ODS Excel), could it be that the file is locked by SAS hence can't be manipulated with Action.ps1? Unlikely I know considering it appears to work without the filter but I don't have the details of your testing regimen.

Answer (score 1):

You have done enough debugging on this for me to wonder if the program is not actually dumping a xlsx file but something different that maybe becomes one after the fact? I don't know anything SAS Customer Intelligence Studio but if you can get the action to trigger manually then I'm on the boat of there is an issue with the filter you are using.

Consider removing the filter and deal with post processing or using a program like [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645) to find what is actually being created in the directory.

An easier way to get the same information would be to follow [BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon)'s suggestion (which should have occurred to me :()

> With your filter set to `'.'` if you add `Write-Host $args[1].FullName` to your `Register-ObjectEvent` script block you can see the full path and extension of the file triggering the event. 
>   Someone else might have a better idea.

Comment: Come to think of it, there was a .bat file at the location at one point, can't remeber quite when. But yeah, It might be a .bat file that changes to excel afterwards, and thus doesnt register as a new xlsx file.